# how to get coordinates on google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have coordinate1

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coor1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
```

I know speed and direction, how can I get new coordinates after time t?
I know, that S(distance) = V(speed) * t(time). But I can't understand how to calculate new point, if I have direction.

Answer (score 1):

If the distance is not too long, you could simply use Pythagoras.

For more accurate results you should check this:
https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils/blob/master/CoreLocationUtils/CLLocation%2Bmeasuring.m

Here you find a function `newLocationAfterMovingAtSpeed` which seems it would exactly serve your needs; you only need to provide the parameters in correct form -- or at least you could learn from the implementation.